# Having an entity without primary key defined when there is only 1 record

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have an Entity Framework Code First MVC3 solution where I have an entity named **Settings** where I only have 1 record in it. This entity is used to store general settings for the solution.

```
public class Settings
{
    public bool   CommunicationActivated { get; set; }
    public string CommunicationMessage { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

When I run the solution, I got the error: *System.Data.Edm.EdmEntityType: : EntityType 'Settings' has no key defined. Define the key for this EntityType.*

**My question**: is it possible to have an entity without key defined? Is it a good idea for an entity with only one record?

Thanks.

Comment: From a DBA perspective, it's never ok to have data in a table that does not have a primary key using MS SQL Server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend that you just add a new column:

```
ID INT NOT NULL IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY
```

This does no harm and allows you to work with the tools, not against them.

You can even ensure that the table only has one record: Set the `ID` field manually to `1` and add a check constraint for `(ID = 1)`.